# Order the growth rate from slowest to fastest

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I am relatively new to Big-O notation and I came across this question:

> Sort the following functions by order of growth from slowest to fastest - Big-O Notation. For each pair of adjacent functions in your list, please write a sentence describing why it is ordered the way it is. 7n^3 - 10n, 4n^2, n; n^8621909; 3n; 2^loglog n; n log n; 6n log n; n!; 1:1^n

So I have got this order -

```
1-> n^8621909
2->7n^3 - 10n 
3->4n^2
4->3n
5->6n log n 
6->n!
7->n
8->n log n
9-> 1.1^n 
10->2^loglogn
```

I am unsure if this would be the correct order or not and also if this is the correct order, I am unsure of how to describe it the way it is because I ordered these in this particular manner using certain values for n and then arranging them.

Answer (score 4):

```
1. n! = O(n!)
2. 1.1^n = O(1.1^n)
3. n^8621909 = O(n^8621909)
4. 7n^3 - 10n = O(n^3)
5. 4n^2 = O(n^2)
6. 6n log n = O(nlogn)
6. n log n = O(nlogn)
8. 3n = O(n)
8. n = O(n)
10. 2^loglog n = O(logn)
```

Some explanations:

- `O(c^n) < O(n!) < O(n^n)` (for some constant `c`)
- `O(n^c) < O(c^n)`
- `2^loglogn` can be reduced to `logn` by setting `2^loglogn = x` and taking the `log` of both sides

Comment: Slowest to fastest (as asked in the question) would be reverse of this?

Comment: so how do you derive this order? I am confused because when I substituted values in n, i then arranged them in order from the biggest to smallest number.

Comment: Actually, you wrong. Since in the expression `2^log log n` logarithm base is omitted, it's really `2^(c log_2 log_2 n + d)` which may be reduced to `O(log n)^k` which is still the smallest one

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 fair comment. My mistake for assuming base 2.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 that particular expression is 2 to the power of loglogn.

Comment: @wookie919 i am still confused how you got your order. How did you get that and why is mine incorrect? Please help me out.

Comment: @Amy You cannot compare the rate of growth of BigO notations by trying some values for `n`. `n` can be arbitrarily big, and the question you need to be asking is, "as `n` grows larger and larger, which one will eventually out-grow the other?" Try comparing `1.1^n` and `n^100` for example. For smaller values of `n`, `n^100` will be larger, but as `n` grows, you will find that `1.1^n` eventually overtakes and grows at a faster rate.